How to concatenate two GeoJSON vectors with different geometry type in QGIS
I have two GeoJSON files with different shape types (Polygons for one and Points for the other) and I would like to concatenate them in a single vector layer that I can export back to GeoJSON.
When using the Merge shapefile tool from QGIS I'm stuck as I'm force to specify the type. Is there another tool I could use to do such a process?



Save both files in GeoJson format (make sure CRS is the same in both of them).
Create a copy of one of them and open it.
Copy and paste the text representing the features in the second layer into the file specified in the previous step.
Make sure the inserted lines end with a comma (it is a GeoJson syntax requirement).

Example data (point and polygon in Merged.geojson file):
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "polygon",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 69.767073345090196, 60.574687803992092 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 69.764689092053032, 60.574741047417163 ], [ 69.767994533763641, 60.576311688995055 ], [ 69.770974850060099, 60.573862519686415 ], [ 69.764960029898162, 60.572211887850678 ], [ 69.764689092053032, 60.574741047417163 ] ] ] } }
]
}



You went faster than me for the same answer !

@Kasper [Blows the smoke out of his revolver and returns it to its holster.]

Step 2 shows, that you are trying to write into a shapefile. This format only supports one geometrytype (point, line, polygon) per file. In general, this is a default behaviour in all GIS, that one datasource should contain one specific geometrytype.
You could try to put your data into an geometry collection.
Do you have access to a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database? You could import the data and do something like this:
-- create some demodata
-- or import
SELECT 'SRID=4326;POINT(50 8)'::geometry as geom INTO demogeom  ;
INSERT INTO demogeom VALUES
('SRID=4326;POLYGON((54 10, 54 9, 50 9, 54 10))'::geometry);

--transform into single GeoJSONS
SELECT ST_AsGEoJSON(geom) FROM demogeom;

--as FeatureCollection
SELECT
  json_build_object(
    'type', 'FeatureCollection',
    'features', json_agg(ST_AsGeoJSON(geom)::json)
  )
FROM
  demogeom;

